# Dropbox sdk repository maven

Tags: dropbox

Even if it sounds like a silly question, I am not able to find the repository where the dropbox sdk is. So in my pom.xml I have declared this dependency:

```
<!-- Dropbox dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dropbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>client2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

But it can not be found in this repository:

```
<repository>
            <id>dropbox-client2</id>
            <url>http://getdropbox.com/developers/</url>
        </repository>
```

Thanks

Comment: I found this thread http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=25418&replies=7#post-158122 Any news about this topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dropbox just release the version 1.6 of it SDK in Java.
And this time they made it available on Maven repository.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.dropbox.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropbox-core-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Checkout for futher updates:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.dropbox.core/dropbox-core-sdk

Answer (score 2):

The official dropbox API is not publish on Maven central repository.
I repackaged it and published on Maven central.

You'll find instruction to add to your project here : https://github.com/vanduynslagerp/dropbox-java-sdk#readme

Answer (score 0):

You can install it on your own repository with:

https://gist.github.com/4543727

Right now, dropbox sdk is version 1.5.3 but you can pass a parameter to retrieve older ones.