# Maven project install jar file complete but not run

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, mysql-connector

It seem like this question [how to add external jar to maven webapp project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665096/how-to-add-external-jar-to-maven-webapp-project)
but when i try to change, nothing happen.
Here my pom.xml

```
-- pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.sk.JDBC</groupId>
  <artifactId>basicAgain</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>basicAgain</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.33</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
-- #pom.xml
```

and when I compile and run in maven:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at com.sk.JDBC.App.main(App.java:28)
```

Can anybody help?
I'm new in English and Maven, fogive me :)
-- Edit
I even use these maven command to install, but not work:
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=src\libraries\mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar `-DgroupId=mysql -DartifactId=mysql-connector-java -Dversion=5.1.33 -Dpackaging=jar`

Comment: Are you using Netbeans? If so, import the MySQL library to your project with it.

Comment: @Lucio: yeah, when I use netbean, everything seem more easy, thank you.But, I just want to know where am I wrong when adding jar file. Everything seem smooth but till run into error.

Comment: Don't know how to deal with ugly XML. If you want to [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle): secondary click on *Libraries*, *Add Library...* Import MySQL JDBC Driver, then select it and press *Add Library*.

Comment: How do you run this jar in maven?

Comment: @Flao: uhmm, I'm run this jar because I don't know how to run.
Plz help :)

Comment: @SaboteurKid it is example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869784/how-to-run-a-maven-created-jar-file-using-just-the-command-line

Comment: @Flao: Hell yeah, that it. Your save me out guys. Thank you so much :) (y)