# Maven doesn't recognize dependencies added in IntelliJ project structure

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, war

I need to use external dependencies for tomcat. I add them to project structures and project build fine. Compiler doesn't show any errors

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/643rW.png)

The project works fine when i run it on IDE.

The problem starts when I try to build WAR file using Maven package :

package org.apache.catalina does not exist

package org.apache.catalina.connector does not exist

package org.apache.coyote does not exist

I've try with all different scope settings but jars aren't found

Comment: Please check this discussion on how to add external jars to maven build: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665096/how-to-add-external-jar-to-maven-webapp-project

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add external jar to maven webapp project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665096/how-to-add-external-jar-to-maven-webapp-project)

Comment: All dependencies need to be listed in the  `pom.xml` as `<dependency>`.